# Transfer Chrome WebStore Extension using Group Publisher Account Between Workspaces

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace, browser-extension, chrome-web-store

Currently I work on a Chrome extension published but unlisted in the Chrome Webstore. Our organisation uses Google Workspace and the extension's owner is bound to a group in the Workspace which Google calls using a 'Group Publisher Account'. We ship the extension to support another application and because of this our documentation describes how to manage the installation of the extension via the Extension ID (the alpha numeric UUID that identifies the extension)

Because of various corporate changes, we'd like to transfer the ownership to a group in a different Google Workspace. In the developer console when we tried to unhook the group publisher account it said that we must unpublish all extensions. While the extensions not being available is a little inconvenient its not the end of the world. However, what we're now concerned about is that unpublishing the extensions, removing the group publisher (at which point ownership will revert to an individual account in the group based on some rules, we think we can arrange for this to be an individual in the new Workspace by adding them as a member of the original Workspace group), and then republishing may cause our extension ID to change. Which is something we really need to prepare for.

Does anyone have an experience with doing this, that could warn us of any landmines we might step on here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the [One Stop Support](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/one_stop_support) form to initiate the transfer request.

1. My item (extension, app, or theme)
2. I want to transfer my item

The form itself calls out a few caveats to be aware of. As of Feb 14, 2022 it stated:

> Please make a note of the following information -
>
> - After submitting this form, you will need to confirm the transfer from the original publisher email address
> - The destination account needs to be registered before submitting this form. A $5 registration fee is required for the registration. Learn more.
> - Ensure you give the correct account details
> - Only items that are published and without any violations will be transferred.
> - Transfers can take up to 7 days

Transfering an extension does not have any impact on end users. The extension ID will be retained, existing installations are not affected, and users will continue to retrieve updates as expected.